# Can POSIX make set a variable from program output?

Tags: makefile, posix

In GNU make, one can do things like `X:=$(shell command -v foo)` to set X to the output of that shell command. Is there a way to achieve the same thing with pure POSIX make?

Answer (score 6):

There is no way in POSIX yet.  There is a [proposal](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=337) which is probably going to be accepted at some point which allows for a `!=` assignment which is similar to using `$(shell ...)`.  Newer versions of GNU make [already support](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html#index-_0021_003d) this syntax, as does BSD make.

```
X != command -v foo
```

Comment: That's great! It works on FreeBSD, although I did find an OS X (10.8.0) machine where it doesn't, on GNU make 3.81 (seems it was added in version 4.0 of GNU make).

Comment: Yes; 3.81 was released in 2006 so doesn't count as "newer" :)

Comment: Just a note: you'll never see a newer version of GNU make shipped with OSX.  Apple hates the GPLv3 and so it will always have much older versions of all GNU programs, from before they switched their licenses to GPLv3 (this is one major reason they invest so much in clang, lldb, etc.)  Another example, the OSX shell is GNU Bash 3.2.57, from 2007, even though newer GNU Bash versions have important new features and standards conformance.  You can use macports or other external OSX repositories to install newer versions of GNU programs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know for POSIX, because GNU make is so ubiquitous, but the standard backtick syntax that you can find in `sh` should be present.

Also, the `:=` construction is GNU specific, so you should use just variable assignment, which is lazy by default. If you can use it lazily, given the tradition of these tools, that it is present in `sh`, and the importance of program output in `make`, it is a reasonable assumption that you can use backticks.

```
X=`command -v foo`
```

Finally, the `make` call always allows the definition of macros in the call:

```
$ make VAR=value VAR=value ... target...
```

Comment: So "lazily" is the key word here – I tried this on BSD and a rule that uses `$(X)` will get that substituted in there after the other variables are evaluated. This also means you can't do tricks like `$($(X)_SOURCES)` if X is set using backticks.

Comment: So if /tmp/test.mk contains 
`X=\`echo foo\`;⮒
Y=foo;⮒
foo_VAR=bar;⮒
all:;⮒
        echo "$(X)";⮒
        echo "$($(Y)_VAR)";⮒
        echo "$($(X)_VAR)"`

then the output is 

`echo "\`echo foo\`"⮒
foo⮒
echo "bar"⮒
bar⮒
echo ""⮒
⮒
`

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea using the output of shell commands as part of the name of `make` variables or macros. I understand that there could be needs in projects that lead you to write that, but it often can be solved in a more straightforward way...

Comment: Diego, I wouldn't be using the `"$($(X)_VAR)"` ;) it's just showing the limits of the backtick method – one can't actually set the variable value to the output (or even set variables depending on whether a command failed or not)

Comment: … this makes it less safe to combine two such backtick-values (unlike `$()` they can't nest), and gives very unreadable output when running without `@`.

Comment: I understand, but you were limited in the first place by using only POSIX features of `make`.

Comment: "the standard backtick syntax that you can find in sh should be present" -- this is incorrect. Backticks, if present inside a rule, would set a variable in the **temporary shell** (usually for that line of the rule only, unless `.ONESHELL` is given), and not inside the **makefile**.